# Dynamic table link to new page

Tags: php

I have a dynamic table that populates using a mysql database. I have rows including the column titles 'bottle name', 'cost', 'size'. They are displayed in the browser using PHP and html.

One of the columns in the sql database is 'description'. I have been set the task of creating a link from bottle name that will take you to  a new page that displays a description of that particular bottle you clicked on. How would I go about creating a link to a page that php would be able to recognize as that particular bottle name in order to recover the description for it? Here is a snippet of my code so far in the populate display php file.

```
                 $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
                 extract ($row); 

                 echo "<tr>\n
                 <td>$bottlename</a></td>\n
                 <td>$cost</td>\n
                 <td>$size</td>\n
                 </tr>\n";
```

Any tips / examples are very much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
                 extract ($row); 

                 echo "<tr>\n
                 <td><a href=\"more_detail.php?bottlename=$bottlename\">$bottlename</a></td>\n
                 <td>$cost</td>\n
                 <td>$size</td>\n
                 </tr>\n";
```

Then in more_detail.php, just do a query in your database for the bottle name and display it's description